# Pass arguments from Rake to a Cucumber scenario

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rake

One of my Rake tasks invokes Cucumber with `Rake::Task[:cucumber].invoke`. Before doing that, my task sets up a set of variables that should be used by the Cucumber scenarios.

What should I do in order to pass a value, available in the Rake task, to the code that runs inside a Cucumber `Before` declaration?

Here is the code I have in Rakefile:

```
task :test, [:site] do |t, args|
    args = args.with_defaults(:site => DEFAULT_SITE)

    $site = args[:site]

    Rake::Task[:cucumber].invoke
end
```

This is how the code in `Before` is right now:

```
Before do
    if $site.ends_with?('.html')
        @engine = PageTester
    else
        @engine = SiteTester
    end
end
```

This code is not supposed to do anything fancy, just select a certain class based on what has been received in the command line. How can I pass the `site` argument to the code inside `Before`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my assumptions was wrong: Rake and Cucumber do not run in the same process, so they do not share the same Ruby VM.

The solution is to use

```
Cucumber::Rake::Task.new do |task|
    task.fork = false
end
```

This will make the `cucumber` task run in the same process of Rake. The problem with this solution is that a crash in Cucumber (on in my code, called from Cucumber scenarios) will bring down the whole Rack. In my case this is an acceptable tradeoff (the only point of my `Rakefile` is to prepare a suitable environment and then run Cucumber in it), for others it may be not.

Answer (score 1):

Setting an environment variable might be easiest:

```
ENV['_SITE'] = args[:site]
```

and in your Before block:

```
if ENV['_SITE'] && ENV['_SITE'].ends_with?('.html')
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I was hoping there be a better way. Both Rack and Cucumber run in the same VM, sharing the variable space. I suppose there is a generic way to make them talk, isn't there?

Comment: How exactly is your cucumber task defined?

Comment: It is just a simple `require 'cucumber/rake/task'; Cucumber::Rake::Task.new`.